# Azure CLI PR List Limit

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I use Azure CLI to query on the list of PRs. Based on the following queries, it seems it has a limit on the number of returned results:

```
$ az repos pr list --status=all --query "length([])"
101

$ az repos pr list --status=completed --query "length([])"
101

$ az repos pr list --status=active --query "length([])"
101

$ az repos pr list --status=abandoned --query "length([])"
101
```

But I wasn't able to find any part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) pointing this out.

Do you know if there's anyway to change this limit?

Comment: This command is working ```az repos pr list --status=all --top 200 ```  here --top is used, is this working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried below command and I use --top for getting the top pull requests like below:

According to [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-list) **`--top`** command states,

> Maximum number of pull requests to list.

```
az repos pr list --status=all --top 200
```

[image]

I have only 10 repos in my environment and got all 10 when used `--top 200`

[image]

If you are not getting the required x number using  `--top x` (x is integer) then I would suggest you to raise a support ticket on the same

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I was assuming that it shows like the whole list if I don't specify `--top`. So it's the other way round 